# Identify this short story based on Kafka's Metamorphosis

Tags: story-identification, short-stories, animals

In probably the early 70s<sup>*</sup> I read a short story, probably intended for teenage readers, that may have been based on or at least similar to Kafka's *Metamorphosis* (*Die Verwandlung*).

The one impression that I was left with at the time that I remember was that the character might be a caterpillar or similar that lived in a basement - in contrast to Kafka's beetle-like "bug". The nature of the creature seemed to be left to the reader's imagination.

I'd like to know the name of the story and its author. I didn't find anything suitable [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Metamorphosis_in_popular_culture#Print).

<sup>*Or it might have been a couple of years earlier and for a younger audience.</sup>

Comment: How does the story go? Does a young man turn into a giant bug overnight? Then what happens? How does it end? How does it differ from Kafka's story, aside from being a different kind of bug?

Answer (score -1):

Could this possibly be Tiptree's "Love is the Plan and the Plan is Death"?
Wikipedia synopsis [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Love_Is_the_Plan_the_Plan_Is_Death).

Comment: How does that story fit the description? What's stopping you from quoting the Wikipedia synopsis in your answer, instead of only the link?

Comment: No. That's not it.